# I draw out the biggest contour in an image. But filling it with color is not working. Any idea??

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to crop out the head portion from an image by changing the cloth color to white pixel value. For that, I have:

1) Crop the image from bottom (10 rows of pixel).

2) Calculate the average color of it and assigned it as cloth color.

3) Make lower and upper color range by manually subtracting and adding 50 pixel of values in average pixel value.

4) Finding contours.

5) Finding the biggest contours and draw it on the image.

Problem is, when drawing biggest contours and filling it with white color, it does not get filled. But if I draw all contours and fill it with white color, it gets filled. What is happening??

My code for cloth detection and changing it to white is:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img4 = cv2.imread('Test.jpg')
img5 = cv2.cvtColor(img4, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

#CLoth detection and removal
crop_img_bottom = img5[490:, :]

bottom_H = np.average(crop_img_bottom[:, :, 0])
bH = int(bottom_H)

bottom_S = np.average(crop_img_bottom[:, :, 1])
bS = int(bottom_S)

bottom_V = np.average(crop_img_bottom[:, :, 2])
bV = int(bottom_V)

lower_cloth_color = np.array([bH-50, bS-50, bV-50])
upper_cloth_color = np.array([bH+50, bS+50, bV+50])
cloth_mask = cv2.inRange(img5, lower_cloth_color, upper_cloth_color)

_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(cloth_mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, 
cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

c = max(contours, key = cv2.contourArea)

cv2.drawContours(img5, c, -1, (255,255, 255), -1) 

cv2.imshow("Cloth", img5)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here are the image:

Original Image

[image: Original Image]

Max contour drawn(white line in cloth boundary(almost))

[image: Max contour drawn]

But if I take out the code for biggest contour and replace c with contours in

```
cv2.drawContours(img5, c, -1, (255,255, 255), -1)
```

as

```
cv2.drawContours(img5, contours, -1, (255,255, 255), -1)
```

I get the following output:

All contour drawn

[image: All contour drawn]

But I need to fill the biggest contour only, so that, it look like only head portion is extracted. What am I doing wrong??

I will change it to BGR later.

Comment: Don’t use contours. Find the largest connected component in `cloth_mask`, which will be easier and more robust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cv2.drawContours` is expecting a list of contours.  If you put `c` into a list in the function as shown, you will get the image below.

```
cv2.drawContours(img5, [c], -1, (255,255, 255), -1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. You saved my day. By the way, any suggestion or idea for removing the remaining cloth parts. .

Comment: You can increase the `inRange` tolerance.  For example, `upper_cloth_color = np.array([bH+100, bS+100, bV+100])` removed more of the shirt outline.  You could also make a mask with the contours and [dilate](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/erosion_dilatation/erosion_dilatation.html) it before using it to mask out the shirt.